# docker-compose push image to aws ecr

Tags: docker, docker-compose

is it possible to have docker-compose both build an image and push it to a remote repo?  right now I do the

`docker-compose`

build then I do

`docker-compose config --services`

loop through the names reconstruct the imagename and the tag, then do

`docker push blah`

Seems like there mush be a way to just ask it to push as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this snippet from the docs at https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build:

> If you specify image as well as build, then Compose names the built
> image with the webapp and optional tag specified in image:

```
build: ./dir
image: webapp:tag
```

> This will result in an image named
> webapp and tagged tag, built from ./dir.

You could at least prepend the image repository in the image name. Then you would should be able to use `docker-compose push` with newer versions of Docker Compose.

Comment: yes this is basically what I'm doing.  but because my compose creates several images, I have to loop the names of those services to create the names of the images to create, then reuse that name to push.  I was hoping docker-compose, since it already knows the name of the image, and all the services I have could do that for me.

Comment: Can you outline in your question why https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/push/ does not work or the additional steps involved? I'm unclear on what you are asking.

Comment: ah, I was hoping someone would bring that up.  The reason is, I don't seem to have it.  my docker-compose version is 1.7.1, but when i do --help it does not list push in there.  I don't know if I need an experimental build or what.  Then I don't know if that's exactly what it does, but if so that would be awesome

Comment: 1.7 is pretty old. How was it installed? Are you able to upgrade?

Comment: is it? damn, well yes, it is, and yes push works as I asked above.  I guess if you want to write a new answer saying "use push dummy"  I'll select it as correct

Comment: I clarified that the above snippet would be coupled with `docker-compose push` on newer versions.

Answer (score 59):

First you need to generate a login for AWS ECR using the `aws ecr get-login-password` command. In bash I did:

```
$ eval $(aws ecr get-login-password)
```

Then for each image, ecr requires you to create a repository before pushing the image.

In my docker-compose.yml file I have a series of services along the lines of:

```
version: '3'
services:
  scheduler:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/pipeline_scheduler
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./docker/scheduler/Dockerfile
   startup:
     image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/pipeline_setup
     build:
       context: ../
       dockerfile: ./docker/startup/Dockerfile
    # etc...
```

In my .env file I set DOCKER_REGISTRY to be the amazon registry location:

```
DOCKER_REGISTRY=919057965832.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

To create the repositories in ecr (using bash again):

```
$ for r in $(grep 'image: \${DOCKER_REGISTRY}' docker-compose.yml | sed -e 's/^.*\///')
> do
>  aws ecr create-repository --repository-name "$r"
> done
```

(The output will show the registry info including the account and region, so you can check/set your .env file at this point if you like).

Then you can build and push the images in the usual way:

```
$ docker-compose build
$ docker-compose push
```

Comment: Seems like `get-login` is deprecated now, should be replaced by `get-login-password`. I've been using `eval $(aws ecr get-login-password --region <region>)` in my scripts.

Comment: This may work great for building, but when [deploying to ECR with the Compose API](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/deploy-applications-on-amazon-ecs-using-docker-compose/), when AWSCLI tries to convert the docker-compose file to CloudFormation, it doesn't resolve the `${DOCKER_REGISTRY}` env var and that results in `pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization`.

Comment: In case if you are windows user like me and need repo names to create repository in ECR, create .bat file and paste below code and run it: 
`FOR /F "delims=/ tokens=1*" %%A IN ('docker images 123.dkr.ecr.ca-region.amazonaws.com/* --format "{{.Repository}}"') DO ( echo %%B
    aws ecr create-repository --repository-name %%B )
PAUSE`