# How can I populate volumes with local content using ECS and docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

## The Situation

I am trying to set up a [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io) / [Grafana](https://grafana.com) cluter using [AWS ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/).  Both Prometheus and Grafana need configuration files.  Normally I would use a volume to pass that kind of information to a docker image.

Since these are two services, I would like to use docker-compose to set them both up and tie them together at once.

## The Attempt

Here's the compose file that I would use for a normal docker setup:

```
version: '3.0'

volumes:
  prometheus_data: {}
  grafana_data: {}

services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
    ports:
      - 9090:9090

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    volumes:
      - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
      - ./grafana/provisioning/:/etc/grafana/provisioning/
    env_file:
      - ./grafana/config.monitoring
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

This does not appear to actually work when I run `ecs-cli compose service up`.  Specifically, the tasks start but then crash, and I'm not seeing any evidence that the configuration files were actually injected.

[This guide](https://medium.com/@journald/prometheus-on-ecs-with-mongodb-exporter-8b58dad1ee8f) explains how to set up a Prometheus image on ECS, but it is actually creating a configured docker image and publishing that image -- it's not using docker compose.

## The Question

Is there a way to inject files (e.g. config files) from my local computer into my ECS images / tasks using docker-compose?

Comment: for ECS I will recommend to put config in docker image instead of mounting from host, it will help you to run in fargate as there is no server in fargate. for example `FROM prom/prometheus copy myconfig.yml /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml`. i

Comment: Thank you @Adiii this is a great suggestion.  if you have time to flesh that out into an answer and I would also mark it as such!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docker-container should be treated differently when it comes to ECS, the above docker-compose seems fine to working with the local setup but with ECS I will not recommend to go for mounting.

So I will recommend putting the config file into the docker image. for example

```
FROM prom/prometheus 
COPY myconfig.yml /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

Also, I will prefer [ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/) as a docker registry in AWS.

The disadvantage of mounting in case of ECS

- You will need to keep config in EC2 instance
- You will not able to use in case of [fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/) as there is no server to manage in fargate
- You will be depended in [AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html) in case of auto-scaling as you docker-container depended on config

Comment: Thank you!  Also, in this case would you manually build images and publish to ECR, or do you know of any handy scripts that you can just say "generate images and update their ECR entries for these three dockerfiles"

Comment: yes, you can push like normal docker registry. here is the complete answer that can help yours. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052999/docker-compose-push-image-to-aws-ecr

Comment: I have deployments in GKE and AWS EC2, easier imho to build custom images for both using [packer](https://packer.io) then leveraging cloud provider specific functionality to scale instance clusters (swarm, kubernetes, ...) using i.e. [Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/AutoScalingGroup.html). ECS tasks are coupled to AWS (more things to maintain if you want to be able to deploy to other cloud providers - I prefer cloud agnostic, docker swarm on my pc is the same as in AWS, etc), ECR not so much - a registry is a registry at the end of the day.